# Perl LWP::useragent capture server response headers

Tags: perl, http-headers, content-type

I'm querying a webserver for a document and I want to capture the both the document and the  related server response headers (esp. Content-Type: ...). I have trouble finding out how to read the headers. Here are some sniplets from my Perl script, I left error checking out for clarity:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent( 'requiredCustomUserAgent' ); # I'm required to set a custom user agent
$imageData = $response->content;         # This is the received document
```

So at this point I can retrieve the web document, but I want to know what Content-Type the server sent with it. Unfortunately this is not always the same as the mime type found by the bash 'file' command. This file-method fails in case of .js or .css documents.

Comment: I think the answer must be in http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTTP-Message-6.03/lib/HTTP/Response.pm and http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTTP-Message-6.03/lib/HTTP/Headers.pm but it seems I just don't know how to read the information on $r->header( $field => $value ) and $h->content_type

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP::Response](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP%3a%3aResponse)

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
my $response = $ua->get("http://google.co.uk");

print $response->headers()->as_string;
print $response->header('content-type');
```

Comment: Just a word of caution. Actually $response->headers->as_string would be expected to produce the raw response headers, but it simply does not. So one should be careful about this output. This is made particularly obvious when one looks at the Set-Cookie value.

Answer (score 0):

the thing that request returns contains a HTTP::Headers object, so look at the docs for HTTP::Headers to see how to use it. For instance

```
my $response = $ua->request($req);       
my $headers = $response->headers();
my @header_field_names = $headers->header_field_names();
$logger->info("$_: ".$headers->header($_)) for grep {/Hogwarts/} @header_field_names;
```